# ChartJS abscissa with a non regular interval

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a graph with ChartJS that shows the duration of connection (1) and disconnection (0):

[This graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2tBS.png)

The interval between two data is always the same even though the data varies between several seconds or several hours, making the graph unreadable.

Is it possible to make this interval larger or smaller depending on the duration? Or do you have to put a fixed interval for the abscissa (per day for example)?

Thanks!